# How to sort a value of a row in mysql

Tags: mysql, sorting

I had a mysql data as

```
id values  
1  1,13,4  
2  12,34,22
```

Now i want this data to sort like

```
id values  
1  1,4,13    
2  12,22,34
```

How can we sort this in mysql query ?

### EDITED ::

Can i get value rearranged from `1,13,4` TO `1,4,13` through mysql query ?

Comment: Are the Values in one field and and 1 row ?

Comment: I would recommend normalizing the column 'values' so that it is as per the standards.

Comment: @BerndBuffen Yes the values are in a one field and in each row

Comment: @VivekViswanathan This is not about normalizing the table with creating another one-to-one record table. I am asking about to sort the field in which numbers exists.

Comment: @Dell If the values column was normalized, it is very easy to get the sorted result. Since the values column has comma separated data, we have to do string processing to sort it (which is not recommended in sql). If there is no way to do normalize it now, you could do the processing on service layer rather than dao layer/sql.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query-

```
SELECT dt.id,GROUP_CONCAT(a.val ORDER BY a.val) FROM 
(SELECT @n := @n + 1 AS val FROM mytable1 dt JOIN (SELECT @n := 0) m LIMIT 1000) a 
JOIN mytable2 dt ON FIND_IN_SET(a.val,dt.values) 
GROUP BY dt.id;
```

Note: change mytable2 with your table.

change mytable1 with any dummy table which contains at least 1000 recrods (max value in your 'value' column of single integer value